# Write an equation in one-column in a two-column article using 'svjour3' package of Springer Journal

Tags: equations, two-column, sv-classes

I am preparing an article for a Springer journal for the first time. I have quite long seen equation to put it in the paper. How can I write it in one column in the two-column article using 'svjour3' package of Springer Journal. Similarly, how can I add 'nomenclature' in the same article.

For the LaTex file see below:

```
%\begin{filecontents*}{example.eps}
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 19 19 221 221
%%CreationDate: Mon Sep 29 1997
%%Creator: programmed by hand (JK)
%%EndComments
%gsave
%newpath
%  20 20 moveto
%  20 220 lineto
%  220 220 lineto
%  220 20 lineto
%closepath
%2 setlinewidth
%gsave
%  .4 setgray fill
%grestore
%stroke
%grestore
%\end{filecontents*}

%
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%

\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\journalname{Springer Journal}
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%% Title%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{Title of the Article}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Authors %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\author{Author's Name}
\institute{Author's Institute Name\\
\email{abcxyz@gmail.com}}
\date{}
\maketitle
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{abstract}
This is an abstract. 
\end{abstract}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\keywords{Keyword1 \and Keyword2\and Keyword3}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\lipsum[1]
The functions $F_1$, $F_2$ and $F_3$  are given below 
\begin{equation}
F(x_{1}, y_{1}, z_{1})=\frac{l x_{0}(1+b+c\sigma)}{\omega(1+b)} P(x_{1}, y_{1}, z_{1})+l\frac{\omega^{2}+b(1+b+c\sigma)}{x_{0}\omega(1+b)^{2}}Q(x_{1},y_{1},z_{1})+\frac{l x_{0}}{\sigma} R(x_{1}, y_{1}, z_{1})
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2-4]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a way to break out of the two-column layout. Instead, I suggest to use the `multline` environment from the `amsmath` package. The example below uses a bit of `\hspace` and `\hfill` to tweak the horizontal alignment of the ensuing multiple rows.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}

\usepackage{calc}

\newlength{\firsttermlength}
\providecommand{\firstterm}{}
\newcommand{\ftspace}{\hspace{\firsttermlength}}

\newcommand{\setfirstterm}[1]{%
\renewcommand{\firstterm}{\ensuremath{#1}}%
\setlength{\firsttermlength}{\widthof{\firstterm}}}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\journalname{Springer Journal}

\begin{document}
\title{Title of the Article}

\author{Author's Name}
\institute{Author's Institute Name\\
\email{abcxyz@gmail.com}}
\date{}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
This is an abstract. 
\end{abstract}
\keywords{Keyword1 \and Keyword2\and Keyword3}

\lipsum[1]
The functions $F_1$, $F_2$ and $F_3$  are given below 
%
% we declare the first term ahead of the multline environment, so that
% its width becomes available for aligning the second and third row. 
% the term itself is available in \firstterm, so that it does not need
% to be repeated.
% 
\setfirstterm{F(x_{1}, y_{1}, z_{1})}
%
\begin{multline}
\firstterm\:=\:\frac{l x_{0}(1+b+c\sigma)}{\omega(1+b)} P(x_{1}, y_{1}, z_{1}) \\[1em] 
\ftspace\: +\:l\frac{\omega^{2}+b(1+b+c\sigma)}{x_{0}\omega(1+b)^{2}}Q(x_{1},y_{1},z_{1}) \\[1em] 
\ftspace\: +\:\frac{l x_{0}}{\sigma} R(x_{1}, y_{1}, z_{1}) \hfill
\end{multline}
\lipsum[2-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]